# C# System.OverflowException binary to decimal and hex conversion

Tags: c#, winforms

I am currently building a c# winform application to convert input from three textboxes, one decimal, one hex and one binary. So you would enter your decimal number in the decimal textbox and the equivalent hex and binary numbers would appear in their respective text boxes. Here is the code I used for the decimal and hex text boxes for the conversions.

```
  private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //conversion to hex and binary for the other texbox's

        if (button20WasClicked == false) { 
           long x = Int64.Parse(textBox1.Text);
           textBox2.Text = Convert.ToString(x,16).ToUpper();

           long y = Int64.Parse(textBox1.Text);
           textBox3.Text = Convert.ToString(y,2);

       }
        else
        {

        }
        button20WasClicked = false;
    }


 private void textBox2_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        if (button20WasClicked == false)
        {
            long x = Int64.Parse(textBox2.Text, System.Globalization.NumberStyles.HexNumber);
            textBox1.Text = Convert.ToString(x, 10);

            long y = Int64.Parse(textBox2.Text, System.Globalization.NumberStyles.HexNumber);
            textBox3.Text = Convert.ToString(y, 2);

        }
        else
        {

        }
        button20WasClicked = false;
    }
```

Now these worked like a dream for converting decimal to hex and binary (textBox1) and hex to decimal and binary (textBox2) but when I try a similar approach on the textbox for inputing binary to convert to decimal and hex I keep getting an overflow exception was unhandled error, value was either too large or small for Int 64. I have tried changing to other size variables but get the same error. Everything I can find on the internet suggests I am on the right track with this  .Convert approach but just can't get anything to work. Here is the code for the final text box causing the error.

```
  private void textBox3_TextChanged_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (button20WasClicked == false)
        {
            long x = Int64.Parse(textBox3.Text);
            textBox1.Text = Convert.ToString(x, 10);

            long y = Int64.Parse(textBox3.Text);
            textBox2.Text = Convert.ToString(y, 16);

        }
        else
        {

        }
        button20WasClicked = false;
    }
```

Any help appreciated as I have been working on this problem for two days now.

Comment: Int64.Parse doesn't know the input is in binary, hence the overflow from interpreting it as a very large decimal number.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not use `Parse` methods.

When you convert `long` to string, you correctly use [Convert.ToString](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6wse73s4(v=vs.110).aspx) overload that allows specifying a base

> public static string ToString(long value, int toBase)

What you are missing is the corresponding reverse [Convert.ToInt64](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yk8t68tb(v=vs.110).aspx) method

> static long ToInt64(string value, int fromBase)

Shortly, change your parsing code in the three places respectively to

```
long x = Convert.ToInt64(textBox1.Text, 10);
long x = Convert.ToInt64(textBox2.Text, 16);
long x = Convert.ToInt64(textBox3.Text, 2);
```

Comment: Had to make some adjustments to another button but the text boxs worked perfect thanks.

Comment: Is there a reason why the Parse methods don't work for this?

Comment: @NicFoster You should ask BCL designers. Probably because there is no standard format/NumberStyle flag for binary. You can see from [reference source](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/parsenumbers.cs,a2f1024cea1a0852) that there is s special utility class used only by `Convert` class methods that supports `base` parameter.